# How can I loop indefinitely, but stop on some condition(s)?

Tags: matlab, loops

I am working on a project in MATLAB. It includes continuous plotting of a data about temperature received from the serial port of the computer. I want to do it infinitely so is there any way to create infinite loops like in C?

Now if is implemented as:

```
while(true)
%comments
end;
```

as Moore stated below, then is there any way to update the flags so that it could be terminated as per requirement or any other operation?

Example: I am plotting the data for my 5 nodes communicating through ZigBee then if ones I have selected to plot 4 nodes on Axis then is there any way after starting the infinite loop so that I could change the data being used inside the loop through an input method of GUI of MATLAB or any flag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an "infinite" loop that can still be easily stopped when a certain condition is met, you can set up your [while condition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) to be a [logical variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html) (i.e. flag) that can be updated within your loop:

```
keepLooping = true;   % A flag that starts as true
while keepLooping
  % Read, process, and plot your data here
  keepLooping = ...;  % Here you would update the value of keepLooping based
                      %   on some condition
end
```

A while loop can also be terminated if a [`break`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) or [`return`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html) command is encountered within the loop.

**EXAMPLE:**

As an example of some of the GUI-based ways you can stop a loop, here is a program that creates a simple GUI that continuously increments and displays a counter once every second using a while loop. The GUI has two ways to stop the loop: a [push button](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) or pressing <kbd>q</kbd> while the figure window has focus (using the [`'KeyPressFcn'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e285730) of the figure to run code when a key is pressed). Just save this code in an m-file somewhere on the MATLAB path and run it to test the example:

```
function stop_watch

  hFigure = figure('Position', [200 200 120 70], ...       % Create a figure window
                   'MenuBar', 'none', ...
                   'KeyPressFcn', @stop_keypress);
  hText = uicontrol(hFigure, 'Style', 'text', ...          % Create the counter text
                    'Position', [20 45 80 15], ...
                    'String', '0', ...
                    'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
  hButton = uicontrol(hFigure, 'Style', 'pushbutton', ...  % Create the button
                      'Position', [20 10 80 25], ...
                      'String', 'Stop', ...
                      'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
                      'Callback', @stop_button);
  counter = -1;
  keepLooping = true;
  while keepLooping       % Loop while keepLooping is true
    counter = counter+1;  % Increment counter
    set(hText, 'String', int2str(counter));  % Update the counter text
    pause(1);             % Pause for 1 second
  end

%---Begin nested functions---

  function stop_keypress(hObject, eventData)
    if strcmp(eventData.Key, 'q')            % If q key is pressed, set
      keepLooping = false;                   %   keepLooping to false
    end
  end

  function stop_button(hObject, eventData)
    keepLooping = false;                     % Set keepLooping to false
  end

end
```

The above example makes use of [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) so that the `'KeyPressFcn'` and button callback can access and modify the value of `keepLooping` in the workspace of the `stop_watch` function.

Comment: Note that this won't work without the `pause` (without `pause` it will finish the loop and then process the queued-up callback events afterwards, defeating the purpose). Note that it's the `drawnow` command which actually processes the queues, and `pause` calls `drawnow` (or does the equivalent), so it's probably better to add a `drawnow` explicitly alongside `pause`, for readability reasons.

Comment: I ran into this issue because I was using a more accurate way to wait, based on `java.lang.Thread.sleep(..)` or `Object.wait(..)` and `java.lang.Thread.yield()`, and that is different from `pause` because these methods do not include the collateral call to `drawnow` (or equivalent).

Answer (score 3):

```
while (true)
    % block of code here
end
```

Comment: Amazing! Almost like EVERY OTHER LANGUAGE :)

Comment: You say how to loop forever, but not how to break out of the loop.